# SQL: How to Store Integer value in CASE function in sql?

Tags: sql-server, database, sybase

I'm working in a Sybase database.I want the 3rd 'WHEN' statement as Integer as output of Original value(**Round((sum(value)*100),1)**). How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
CASE  WHEN Round((sum(value)*100),1)<0 THEN 'Neg' 
      WHEN Round((sum(value)*100),1)=0 THEN 'N/A'
      WHEN Round((sum(value)*100),1)>0 THEN  Round((sum(value)*100),1)

END AS RCB
```

Note: here 3rd row indicating error as it is an integer.The error, I'm getting is :
 **Error:-** `Data exception - data type conversion is not possible. In CASE expression, incompatible data type at result expression 3, ROUND(COALESCE ((SUM(MSTR.SUM.value)*100),0),1)`

**Secondly** , I tried with Else statement below.

```
CASE  WHEN Round((sum(value)*100),1)<0 THEN 'Neg' 
      WHEN Round((sum(value)*100),1)=0 THEN 'N/A'
     --WHEN Round((sum(value)*100),1)>0 THEN Round((sum(value)*100),1)
      ELSE Round((sum(value)*100),1)
END AS RoRC,
```

But still getting the same error. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Add some sample data and desired output

Comment: You can't mix data types; you need the result of each `WHEN` to be either all strings or all numbers.

Comment: @Mattew Strawbridge, That's why I'm asking if there is  a way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [cast](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Cast.htm) the number as `varchar` to match the type of other possible results of CASE statement

```
CASE  WHEN Round((sum(value)*100),1)<0 THEN 'Neg' 
      WHEN Round((sum(value)*100),1)=0 THEN 'N/A'
      WHEN Round((sum(value)*100),1)>0 THEN  CAST(Round((sum(value)*100),1) as varchar)
```

Comment: It's working.Thanks a lot Vojtech Dohnal .The output for 3rd condition is (according to my sql database) = 27.000000000000. previously it was 27. So can you help me to get 27.0 as a result .?

Comment: Try this using CAST to force the numer of decimal places `CAST(CAST(Round((sum(value)*100),1) as numeric(9,1)) as varchar)`

Comment: Again Thank you so much . It's working fine as aspected.